# How to get const from static class C#?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have static class with conts inside:

```
static class RestfulPaths {
    static string BASE_URL = "A";
    static string SYNC_CHECK = "A";
}
```

In another class I try to get const as:

```
RestfulPaths.BASE_URL
```

Comment: What happens when you do?

Comment: You should make your properties public.

Comment: The properties are not made `public`. Also they are not const. You need `public const string BASE_URL`

Comment: [csharp static-classes-and-static-class-members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members)

Answer (score 0):

Make your class and its properties also `public`, then you'll get them from the other class.

```
public static class RestfulPaths
        {

            public static string BASE_URL = "A";

            public static string SYNC_CHECK = "A";

        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
public static class RestfulPaths {
    public static string BASE_URL = "A";
    public static string SYNC_CHECK = "A";
}
```

Comment: Do you have anything to say, or are you here just to dump code and leave?

Comment: I am sorry, what is wrong with my answer?  What exactly you want to hear more?